# Can importResource method return diag.Diagnostics in Terraform SDK v2?

Tags: terraform

Context: I'm developing a TF Provider and noticed that all CRUD methods return `diag.Diagnostics`:

```
// See Resource documentation.
type CreateContextFunc func(context.Context, *ResourceData, interface{}) diag.Diagnostics

// See Resource documentation.
type ReadContextFunc func(context.Context, *ResourceData, interface{}) diag.Diagnostics

// See Resource documentation.
type UpdateContextFunc func(context.Context, *ResourceData, interface{}) diag.Diagnostics
```

([code pointer](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/blob/main/helper/schema/resource.go#L625-L634))

*but*

`Import` method returns `([]*ResourceData, error)` instead of `diag.Diagnostics`:

```
type ResourceImporter struct {
    // Deprecated: State is deprecated in favor of StateContext.
    State StateFunc

    StateContext StateContextFunc
}
type StateContextFunc func(context.Context, *ResourceData, interface{}) ([]*ResourceData, error)
```

Is there a workaround for `diag.Diagnostics` -> `error` (we could use `diag.FromErr(err)` the other way around.

Unfortunately I can't use

```
StateContext: schema.ImportStatePassthroughContext,
```

([code pointer](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/blob/main/helper/schema/resource_importer.go#L50))

Answer (score 0):

I could use `fmt.Errorf(diagError[0].Summary)` for inverse conversion.